# Fading Android Title Bar

Tags: android

So I am following the steps to create [WebView-based Applications](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/webview/gettingstarted) for Android. And I have successfully removed the Notification and Title bar from the app. Though whenever I open the app the title bar for it is visible for a split second. How could I remove this? Below is the code I have to remove it from the App:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

PS. I am no Android developer, so I will try to understand your input as best as possible.

**EDIT:** This app I am building needs to support 2.2 and up, and when I run this on a phone with 2.3 the title bar is still visible. What else do I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

Change the theme in the Android Manifest file to something with no title bar or full screen.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity theme use `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>`

Answer (score 0):

**If you are Using this**

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

in Application Tag of your Menifest file.

**Then You have to remove from your Code:**

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: By adding this, the app doesn't open.

Comment: Even after removing that code the app still won't start.

Comment: Then you have to post your erorr logcat